# How to replace strawberry shake websocket client?

Tags: graphql, integration-testing, hotchocolate

I need to replace strawberry shake web socket client with asp .net test server one for end to end testing is it possible? I was able to replace http client which used for queries and mutations with test server one by registering `IHttpClientFactory` but I don't know how to do the same for web sockets.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. We also have an in-memory client that is intended for integration testing.

Comment: @MichaelIngmarStaib Please show me how I have read HC source code along with its tests and I am still unsure how to do it. I need to make strawberry shake to use web socket client coming from `WebApplicationFactory`. I am doing end to end testing of my server (I used wrong term in my now edited question) making requests as a client would and asserting responses. I am trying to avoid mocking as much as possible so the test are as close as possible to real application. I can provide minimal repo if answer is too long or complicated.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've found to test with HC and Strawberry Shake is to use the in-memory client and test against the HC GraphQL server directly, rather than using the `WebApplicationFactory`. This has the benefit of preserving the `async` flow, although you won't be able to test ASP specific things like authentication this way.

Add a reference to the in-memory client.

```
<PackageReference Include="StrawberryShake.Transport.InMemory" Version="12.6.0" />
```

In `graphqlrc.json` modify your default transport profile (or add a new one, more work to explain).

```
"transportProfiles": [
    {
      "name": "Default",
      "default": "InMemory",
      "subscription": "InMemory"
    }
  ]
```

Now when you configure your `IServiceCollection`

```
services
    .AddGraphQL()
    .BuildDefaultSchema();

services
    .AddGraphQLTestClient()
    .ConfigureInMemoryClient();
```

Where `BuildDefaultSchema` is specific to you (i.e. this is how you configure the `IRequestExecutorBuilder`). And the name of the method `AddGraphQLTestClient` will vary depending on what you called your client in `graphqlrc.json`.

That's basically it. Resolve your Strawberry Shake client and it will just work.